Writes add up to "Bytes unrepaired"
For testing purpose, I am using NoSQLBench to load the data on Cassandra 5.x. Its a 3 nodes cluster. I've noticed that when rampup(load) phase completes, the size of Bytes unrepaired reaches to the amount of data loaded / written.
Same happened when I use the data folders from a backup created using Cassandra 4.x. The data there was around 167GB.
I want to know if it's an unusual behaviour or the expected one. Is it normal to have bytes unrepaired every time after bulk writes or bulk loading data.

Thanks for posting on Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Incremental repairs have been the default since Cassandra 2.2 (CASSANDRA-7250). SSTables which have already been repaired are flagged with a repairedAt so they don't get repaired again, making repairs more efficient since only unrepaired SSTables are checked for inconsistencies.
As you would expect, any new data on a node is by definition unrepaired until such time that a repair runs so this data is added to the "unrepaired bucket". As more data is loaded to a node, the more unrepaired data will grow. Cheers!

This is expected behavior - and maybe the wording "unrepaired" is misunderstood.
You just inserted data into Cassandra - and no repairs have run since then. So the newly inserted data is written to sstables and is counted there.
Repairs are essential in any Cassandra cluster and there are two types of them: full and incremental repairs.
In newer versions since full repairs affect performance a lot there are incremental repairs, which are not running over the entire set of sstables. To be able to do incremental repairs, Cassandra keeps track if an sstables has been repaired during an incremental repair or not - this is where the number you see comes from.
So you can think of to pools of tables - repaired ones or need to be repaired ones. The number gives you a hint of how much data needs to be repaired.
The repair itself ensures that your data is consistent over all nodes in your cluster according to your replication factor (no lost writes, updates or deletes).
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/operating/repair.html
